# Django on Openshift, keeping config files different in different environments

Tags: python, django, git, openshift

I'm just getting started with deploying a Django application that I've already developed onto Openshift.  I've gotten the app created and the environment set up correctly (as far as I can tell), and now I'm able to `git push` my committed changes to Openshift.

I use my home Linux desktop as a development machine, and as you can imagine there are settings which are different between the two environments -- database login information, paths, etc.  My question is, how can I develop at home, push changes to Openshift, and still most easily maintain my settings on both systems?  I already know about `.gitignore` but my understanding is that that only has an effect when you're first committing into your repository.  And if I want to begin ignoring additional files later, I could see that becoming difficult to maintain.

Is it better to replace those values in settings.py with environment variables that hold different values in different environments?  Like defining the $OPENSHIFT_HOME_DIR on my local machine as well?  That seems a bit hacky.

How should I tackle this?  I'd be interested in hearing from anyone who either does this on Openshift or on other systems with a similar environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should make different settings files for different environments. You can make a base.py file to contain the common settings and then import it in dev.py and production.py and define environment specific settings there

Check this project's layout : https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name/project_name

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem too. I tried what @Arsh Singh said, creating file for base, dev and production and set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to `settings.production` on Openshift. 
But, I get error just because openshift can't find the settings file.

If you want only run your production(openshift) and dev(local machine) versions, you can set your environment variables to openshift on a action_hook called pre_start_python-2.7.
The path the file is: `.openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_python-2.7`

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DEV_MACHINE="False"
export EMAIL_HOST='smtp.example.com'
```

It's just work for me, but there any problem with it.
The first is if you want change any value on your environment variables, you should push a commit. Another problem is that isn't a good practices put your sensitive settings like passwords, paths on git. It's just for code.
Another problem that I have was when needed run a third environment for Staging, then this solution aren't suitable.

Then, to solve the problem again, I used the Frabric[1] to run some commands on openshift.
My solution consist in create a folder called config on my django application. 
Inside this folder, create three files, `local_env.txt2`, `staging_env.txt2` and `production_env.txt2`.
In this files, I have a json dict, like this:

```
{
    "DEV_MACHINE": "True",
    "EMAIL_HOST":"smtp.gmail.com"
}
```

Then, to send the environment variable to openshift, I created the following code that just read the config file and send to openshift. The file name of this code should be `fabfile.py`.

```
"""Management utilities."""

from fabric.api import abort, env, local, settings, task, run, sudo, cd
from fabric.operations import put
import json

# DEPLOY ON OPENSHIFT

@task
def staging_site():
    """Staging config for deployment on openshift"""
    env.environment_variables = "config/staging_env.txt2"
    env.environment = "staging"
    env.app_name = '<staging project name on openshift>' # 

@task
def production_site():
    """Production config for deployment on openshift"""
    env.environment_variables = "config/production_env.txt2"
    env.environment = "production"
    env.app_name = '<production project name on openshift>'

@task
def set_envs_openshift(args=""):
    """
    Setup all evironmnt variables
        Example of usage:
            * fab staging_site setup_envs_openshift

        if you are logged in more than one accont on openshift, use it:
            * fab staging_site setup_envs_openshift:'-l <account email>'

    """
    unset_envs_openshift(args)
    # run locally command
    str_envs = open(env.environment_variables, 'r').read()
    json_envs = json.loads(str_envs)
    env_list = ''
    for k, v in json_envs.items():
        env_list += ' %s="%s" ' % (k, v)

    local("rhc env set %s -a %s %s" % (env_list, env.app_name, args))
    local("rhc app-stop -a %s %s" % (env.app_name, args))
    local("rhc app-start -a %s %s" % (env.app_name, args))

@task
def unset_envs_openshift(args=""):
    """
    Unset all environment variables on openshift.
        Example of usage:
            * fab staging_site unset_envs_openshift
    """

    str_envs = open(env.environment_variables, 'r').read()
    json_envs = json.loads(str_envs)
    keys_list = ''
    for k in json_envs.keys():
        keys_list += ' %s ' % k
    local("rhc env unset %s -a %s %s --confirm" % \ 
        (keys_list, env.app_name, args))

# END DEPLOY ON OPENSHIFT
```

Then, to deploy your environment variables, run it:

```
fab production_site setup_envs_openshift
```

Hope that helps.